# OpenCR1.0 12V output plug

Tags: ros, ros-kinetic, turtlebot3, opencr

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The OpenCR1.0 board on the Turtlebot 3 Burger has a 12V output supplied through a [SMW250-02](http://www.alldatasheet.com/datasheet-pdf/pdf/148144/YEONHO/SMW250-02P.html) socket. Has anybody been able to find an easily purchasable plug that fits this socket?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/281847/opencr1.0-12v-output-plug/) by [karbear](https://answers.ros.org/users/33571/karbear/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2018-02-05

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [muddy](https://answers.ros.org/users/35466/muddy/) on 2018-05-25**:
were you able to find this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi :)

we provide everything for the OpenCR so you can create it yourself. please see : https://github.com/ROBOTIS-GIT/OpenCR-Hardware
If you want another socket to replace SMW250-02, you can find it here.

https://kr.misumi-ec.com/vona2/detail/222005579844/?HissuCode=SMW250-02&searchFlow=results2similartn

---

Originally posted by [Gilbert](https://answers.ros.org/users/33787/gilbert/) with karma: 41 on 2018-02-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0